# Load External Libraries in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I have Service directory in my symfony application like below

> src/SwipeBundle/Service

Inside of this directory I have class called.

> RSA.php

This class has

```
namespace SwipeBundle\Service;


require_once __DIR__ . 'RSA/Crypt/RSA.php';
require_once __DIR__ . 'RSA/File/X509.php';

class RSA
{
    public function privateKey() {
        require_once __DIR__ . 'RSA/Certificates/private.txt';
    }

    public function certificates() {
        return require_once __DIR__ . 'RSA/Certificates/pinew.cer';
    }
}
```

and the files directory are

> src/SwipeBundle/Service/RSA/Certificates/pinew.cer
>   src/SwipeBundle/Service/RSA/Certificates/private.txt
>   src/SwipeBundle/Service/RSA/Crypt/RSA.php
>
> src/SwipeBundle/Service/RSA/File/X509.php

I want to load the classes of this service class to my Controller, like so.

**Controller**

```
    use SwipeBundle\Service;

    class BillsPayController extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction() {

            $rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();
            $hash = new \Crypt_Hash('sha1');
            $x509 = new \File_X509();

            $privatekey = file_get_contents(RSA()->privateKey());
            $x509->loadX509(file_get_contents(RSA()->certificates()));

        }
}


I tried also using this one.

use SwipeBundle\Service\RSA;

    class BillsPayController extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction() {

            $a = new RSA();
            $a->privateKey();

        }
}
```

Error I encountered.

```
    Attempt result 1: Attempted to load class "Crypt_RSA" from the global namespace.
    Did you forget a "use" statement?

   Attempt result 2: Compile Error: main(): Failed opening required '/Users/jaysonlacson/Sites/contactless/src/SwipeBundle/ServiceRSA/Crypt/RSA.php' (include_path='.:')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a forward slash like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/RSA/Crypt/RSA.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/RSA/File/X509.php';
```

I'm just guessing, but can you try that?